# How to add Cookie Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cookie, magento-2.0

I want to add a **COOKIE** with value and some duration, how to do it in magento 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

IMO the best approach would be to create a class to wrap the cookie creation and then just use it where you want.

**The Cookie Class**

> {Vendor}/{Module}/Cookie/Example.php

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Module\Cookie;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class Example
{
    /**
     * Name of cookie that holds private content version
     */
    const COOKIE_NAME = 'example';

    /**
     * CookieManager
     *
     * @var CookieManagerInterface
     */
    private $cookieManager;

    /**
     * @var CookieMetadataFactory
     */
    private $cookieMetadataFactory;

    /**
     * @var SessionManagerInterface
     */
    private $sessionManager;

    /**
     * @param CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager
     * @param CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory
     * @param SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        CookieManagerInterface $cookieManager,
        CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
    ) {
        $this->cookieManager = $cookieManager;
        $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get form key cookie
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get()
    {
        return $this->cookieManager->getCookie(self::COOKIE_NAME);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @param int $duration
     * @return void
     */
    public function set($value, $duration = 86400)
    {
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration($duration)
            ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
            self::COOKIE_NAME,
            $value,
            $metadata
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function delete()
    {
        $metadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory
            ->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration(0)
            ->setPath($this->sessionManager->getCookiePath())
            ->setDomain($this->sessionManager->getCookieDomain());

        $this->cookieManager->deleteCookie(
            self::COOKIE_NAME,
            $metadata
        );
    }
}
```

> This example was based on [Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\FormKey](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/PageCache/FormKey.php)
> and represent a single cookie with name "example"

If you want to add some custom properties to the $metadata ([PublicCookieMetadata](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PublicCookieMetadata.php)) as change the path,http_only, etc you should refactor the `set()` and/or `delete()` method(s).

**How to use it**

You can access that class simply using the Object Manager in almost anywhere (Ugly Approach):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Vendor\Module\Cookie\Example')
    ->set('value', 3600);
```

Depending "where" you need to create the cookie you can take a look at the constructor of your class maybe you already have an Object manager there, if not you can also inject it in the constructor.

Comment: @J. John, Hey! i juts saw that you accept the answer while i've been editing it, just take a look now, because i made several changes in order to simplify the implementation.

Comment: I've to edit `createCookieMetaData()` to `createPublicCookieMetadata()` in `set` method to resolve the error (fatal error). Smart approach though!

Comment: what's the difference between `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface` used by you and `Magento\Framework\Session\Config\ConfigInterface` used in `Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager`?

Comment: @MauroNigrele function call in set and delete method should be createPublicCookieMetadata instead of createCookieMetadata

Comment: @MauroNigrele I agree with @shivam. `createPublicCookieMetadata()` would be the way to go b/c other methods such as `setDuration()` are not available using `createCookieMetadata()`. BTW, this is on 2.1.

Comment: Why the cookie wrapper class should go under `Vendor\Module\Cookie`, why not  `Vendor\Module\Model\Cookie.php`?

Comment: Hey, great solution (after the `Public` fix), but the cookie only saves for me when I'm on backend. Could you help me with that? Thanks. [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177495/magento-2-saving-cookies-work-only-on-backend)

Comment: Guys. I've proposed changes because `$this->createPublicCookieMetadata()` doesn't exist in this class. It should be `$this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata()` [See in magento repo](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/Cookie/CookieMetadataFactory.php#L50). But I've get 2 rejects. LOL...

Comment: Works perfectly. But please don't promote using the Object Manager to use this approach. Injecting the class in the constructor is the way to go - always.

Comment: If you're using these get/set/delete cookie functions in a Block (phtml), make sure to set the block as `cacheable = false` in your layout xml. Otherwise it won't work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You can set & get cookie using php basic function like this:

```
//set cookie
$cookie_name = "magento";
$cookie_value = "How to Cookie";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time()+3600); /* expire in 1 hour */

//get cookie
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
```