# Magento2: How to create and delete cookies

Tags: magento2, cookie

I've followed [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100136/how-to-add-cookie-magento-2) question but `set` method mentioned there is outdated (Reference: [Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\FormKey::set()](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/PageCache/FormKey.php)).

So, a cookie is created like this:

```
public function set($value, PublicCookieMetadata $metadata)
{
    $this->cookieManager->setPublicCookie(
        self::COOKIE_NAME,
        $value,
        $metadata
    );
}
```

Where `$metadata` should be an instance of `PublicCookieMetadata`.

In one of the plugin I'm using `$this->customerCountry->set('India', 10);` I know I'm doing wrong here. Instead of passing `10` as the second parameter I need to pass instance of `PublicCookieMetadata`. How I can do that? I've tried `$this->customerCountry->set('India', PublicCookieMetadata $metadat =null);` which seems to be wrong. How I can creat and set duration of the cookie?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to declare in your class constructor an instance of  `\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory` like this:

```
protected $cookieMetadataFactory;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory $cookieMetadataFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->cookieMetadataFactory = $cookieMetadataFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then you can get generate the `PublicCookieMetadata` like this

```
$cookieMetadata = $this->cookieMetadataFactory->createPublicCookieMetadata()
            ->setDuration(lifetime goes here)
            ->setPath(cookie path goes here)
            ->setDomain(domain goes here)
            ->setSecure(is secure goes here)
            ->setHttpOnly(http only flag goes here);
```

then use the variable `$cookieMetadata` as your parameter.

You can find examples of you to generate the cookie metadata in

- `\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session::prolong()`
- `\Magento\Persistent\Model\Session::setCookie()`
- `\Magento\Sales\Helper\Guest::setGuestViewCookie()`
- `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreCookieManager::setStoreCookie()`