# How to Use Session or Cookie in Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, cookie, customer-session

I am going to add Age verification block on Home page. for that i want to set session or cookie variable. so that i can check it through out all pages of store weather age verification session or cookie set or not.

Comment: The block only show on Homepage?

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100136/how-to-add-cookie-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below classess to set cookie and session in your block by passing into dependency.

> Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;
>
> Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory;
>
> Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PublicCookieMetadata;
>
> Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface;

For reference [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100136/how-to-add-cookie-magento-2)

Hope it helps.