# Magento 2 session id cookie - where to find it?

Tags: magento2, session, cookie, customer-session

I have custom php script located inside pub/. It doesn't use Magento objects to limit spent resources because it is called at each page load with ajax call.

Inside that script I need to check if data saved to cookie inside Magento observer is from the same Magento session or not.

In Magento 1 it was easy by using `$_COOKIE['frontend']`. Each time I saved data to cookie I also saved information about $_COOKIE['frontend']. When I read cookie value I also checked if `$_COOKIE['frontend']` is still the same as it was when I saved the cookie information.

Now with Magento 2 there is no cookie with name frontend, I found useful cookies just cookie `PHPSESSID`, but this is probably not the same as Magento session id. At least with Magento 1 it was different, it could last different time as Magento session id. So how does Magento 2 check Magento session id, is in Magento 2 the same as `PHPSESSID`?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135370/how-to-use-session-or-cookie-in-magento-2-0 or https://webkul.com/blog/set-get-data-cookie-magento2/

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, I need to find out current Magento session id outside Magento objects inside custom php script to compare if current session is still the same as it was when I stored custom cookie value inside Magento class.