# Magento 2: How to use Cookie?

Tags: magento2, javascript, cookie

How can we use cookie in magento 2 to store data..

i'm trying to store data in cookie, on 
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/resource-url-manager.js` 
to store selected estimated shipping method,

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`app/code/Custom/Module/view/frontend/templates/sample.phtml`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/jquery.cookie'
    ], function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var check_cookie = $.cookie('foo'); // Get Cookie Value
            var date = new Date();
            var minutes = 60;
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
            $.cookie('foo', '', {path: '/', expires: -1}); // Expire Cookie
            $.cookie('foo', 'bar', {expires: date}); // Set Cookie Expiry Time
            $.cookie('foo', 'setvalue'); // Set Cookie Value
        });// You need to add ); to correct burg in your code
    }); 
</script>
```

Helpful Article on PHP Side: https://webkul.com/blog/set-get-data-cookie-magento2/

Comment: As @rakesh-jesadiya states below, you should be using `mage/cookie` for most use cases. Doing so will automatically use the cookie config for the Magento store without needing to explicitly define them with `jquery/jquery.cookie`.

Answer (score 12):

In the `target.phtml`, add js codes like below.

### Set the cookies

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/jquery.cookie'
    ], function ($) {
       $.cookie('cookie_name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });//Set the cookies
    });
</script>
```

`jquery/jquery.cookie` is defined in the file `lib/web/jquery/jquery.cookie.js`. Below is parameter description.

#### expires

Define when the cookie will be removed. Value must be a `Number` which will be interpreted as days from time of creation or a `Date` instance. If omitted, the cookie becomes a `session cookie`.

#### path

If you want get the value from another page, notice the **path** setting `{ path: '/' }`.

Because **cookies are only accessible to the specified path and any subpaths** , more discussion about this you could see here [Cookie path and its accessibility to subfolder pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576535/6851965).

---

### Get the cookies

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/jquery.cookie'
    ], function ($) {
        var temp = $.cookie('cookie_name');//Get the cookies
    });
</script>
```

---

### Supplement

#### mage/cookies

`mage/cookies` could replace `jquery/jquery.cookie`, it did some initialization work which you could see it in the file `lib/web/mage/cookies.js`.

Usage: `$.mage.cookies.set('name', 'value', {lifetime: -1});`

#### use cookie in PHP

You could use the php class in this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100142/44237

Comment: how to use this cookies on observer or controller

Comment: I try with above code but i am not getting cookie value in another page.

Comment: Also i was checked in console but i can't find there.

Comment: @ChiragPatel Do you set the path right? Cookies are only accessible to the specified path and any subpaths.

Comment: @KeyShang Thanks! i solved my problem there is a problem with my code.

Comment: @SarveshTiwari You could use the php class in this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100142/44237

Answer (score 11):

You can store cookie in js file using below method,

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/cookies'
], function ($) {
    $.cookie('cookiename', cookievalue);
});
```

Comment: `mage/cookies` is for Magento 1?

Comment: @AnkitShah mage/cookies is also working in magento 2.

Comment: Any idea how to set an expiration date using this method @RakeshJesadiya?

Comment: @BenCrook,  $.cookie('foo', '', {path: '/', expires: -1}); is not working for you?

Comment: Turns out it expires with the user's session by default which is what I needed. Related question, is there any difference between `$.cookie()` and  `$.mage.cookies.set()`?

Comment: i havent try with $.mage.cookies.set() yet.

Comment: In Magento 2.1.8, it shows `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($) {
            $.cookie('cookiename', '123');
        }`

Comment: OK, find the error solution, we need change `define` to `require` in the codes.

Comment: How to get cookie in another page?

Answer (score 9):

Use `mage/cookies` as `jquery/jquery.cookie` is removed in 2.4.5

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/cookies'
], function ($) {
    $.cookie('cookiename', cookievalue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below to store data inside cookie. Here is the code,

```
<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'jquery/jquery.cookie',
    'domReady!'
], function($) {
  var data = "store my data";
  $.cookie('my_data', data );
  console.log($.cookie('my_data'));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need to open or not a modal after the cookie check:

```
 require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'jquery/jquery.cookie'
    ],
```

this is the correct order otherwise the modal will not work

Answer (score 0):

How to add when i open a report in magento. I see the ajax url loading to display content into grid. How to check ajax url loading and add cookie for that ajax?
or How to disable ajax loading for ui component grid listing in magento 2?

Comment: you can create a separate question for your query.. no one will identify your question here..

Answer (score 0):

For those of you struggling with setting php cookie and accessing it in js:

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$metadata = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadataFactory')
->createPublicCookieMetadata()
->setPath('/')
->setHttpOnly(false);

$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Stdlib\CookieManagerInterface')->setPublicCookie('cookieexample','Error', $metadata);

The result was a cookie with the domain .example.shop.com

When I set an empty domain as parameter $.cookie('foo', 'bar', { domain: '' });

I get a cookie with the domain example.shop.com and everything works fine.