# On popup after subscribe page got refresh and popup appear again

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, popup

I am doing popup in magento2 and my code is like . When I click subscribe button page got refresh and again it appear . So I am in infinty loop . How in magento we make it for 1 time session on home page ?

```
<div id="custom-popup-modal">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="static_content">
            <h5 class="min-title">JOIN THE PARTY</h5>
            <h2 class="min-title">GET 15% OFF YOUR FIRST ORDER*</h2>
            <p class="content">Subscribers only discounts, first look at new products, and cutting-edges tips</p>
            <?php echo $newsletterHtml; ?>
            <p class="micro-text">*Promo code will be emailed to the address you enter, New subscribers only</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 img-section">
        <img src='<?php echo $this->getUrl('pub/media/').'cms/image-email.gif'; ?>' />
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">

    require(['jquery','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'],

        function($,modal) {

            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#custom-popup-modal'));
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                $('#custom-popup-modal').modal('openModal');
            });
        }
    );

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. You can set Cookie time accordingly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'mage/cookies'
    ],function($,modal) {
            if(!$.cookies.get("foo")){
                var date = new Date();
                var minutes = 60;
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
                $.cookie('foo', '', {path: '/', expires: -1}); // Expire Cookie
                $.cookie('foo', 'bar', {expires: date}); // Set Cookie Expiry Time
                $.cookie('foo', 'setvalue'); // Set Cookie Value
              }
                var options = {
                    type: 'popup',
                    responsive: true,
                };
                var popup = modal(options, $('#custom-popup-modal'));
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    $('#custom-popup-modal').modal('openModal');
                });
            }
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: is it working ??

Comment: let me check please

Comment: where to set time ?  in lifetime place ?

Comment: `var cookie = $.mage.cookies['defaults']['lifetime'];` here

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163345/magento-2-how-to-use-cookie

Comment: I still didnt get what to write instead of 'defaults' and 'lifetime' ? :(

Comment: Please tell me cookie time that you don't want to display popup?

Comment: I want basically  , till one user  is on web page it should not appear again ? is it possible ?

Comment: if the same user come back to website some another day then you want to display?

Comment: yes then aswell I want to show.

Comment: I updated my code

Comment: Now I am not on workplace , I will test morning thank you for your time brother .