# Magento 2.2- stop newsletter popup to display on all pages

Tags: magento2.2, newsletter, popup

I am using cleversoft novetty theme. 
My newsletter pop-up appears on all pages that's so irritating. I want it to display only once at homepage whenever someone visits my site.
here is the coding of default.xml :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="newsletter_head_components" template="Magento_Newsletter::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

What can I change in this so that it displays only on front page and not on all pages?

Comment: If you are ready to purchase the extension you can check out this extension [newsletter popup](https://www.mageants.com/newsletter-popup-extension-for-magento-2.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `cms_index_index.xml` and add your code to show popup only on Home page

**For Custom theme:**

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

**For custom Module:**

> app/code/{Vendor}/{Module}/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="head.components">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="newsletter_head_components" template="Magento_Newsletter::js/components.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Set cookie to show popup only one time. Refer this answer for how you can set and get cookie: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/100142/35758

Answer (score 0):

> Stores -> Configuration -> CLEVERSOFT EXTENSIONS

Open **CleverNewsletter** Option

there have option **Selected pages** open it ->

select No from **Show on All pages** and select page you want to set NEwsLetter