# Cookie to display popup only one time on homepage

Tags: magento2, javascript, newsletter

I want to set a cookie to display my popup only one time on the homepage. Any suggestions how can I do that?
Here is the code of , my newsletter popup

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"><body>
<referenceBlock name="head.components">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="newsletter_head_components" template="Magento_Newsletter::js/components.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer></body>
```

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100136/how-to-add-cookie-magento-2/100142#100142

Comment: @piyush i am using magento 2.2 and i didn't find any folder named >vendor/module/cookie...

Comment: and i also dont know what is going to be the code for popup display only one time

Comment: where to paste this code?

Comment: There is also a CookieHelper in mage/cookies (lib/web/mage/cookies.js) for javascript