# Full page cache issue with cookie in M2

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, cookie

I have set cookie value using onclick event.

At page load i want to check cookie value so have create module as explained in this [How to add Cookie Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100136/how-to-add-cookie-magento-2) url.

everything is working properly but when i enable FPC , i can't get updated value from cookie.

can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, FPC cause issues with cookies. I think for the solution you need check cookie after the page load using `XHR` request.